# how to convert string to array in javascript without additional " and ,

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I have a input with this value and I want to get data and convert to javascript array.
I want to convert this:

```
<input name="news_album" type="hidden" value="[1SoW6zxJ58udU6gfT2G2bSZTf.jpg","2DhY7TjqXeqWNLaVN…DtEH1csjo11.jpg","PN7QSI3lQeQHOdmwfCrjbixkg.png"]">
```

to as a Array in javascript:

```
["1SoW6zxJ58udU6gfT2G2bSZTf.jpg","2DhY7TjqXeqWNLaVN.jpg","DtEH1csjo11.jpg","PN7QSI3lQeQHOdmwfCrjbixkg.png"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign an id to it and correct the quotes

```
<input id="news_album" name="news_album" type="hidden" value='["1SoW6zxJ58udU6gfT2G2bSZTf.jpg","2DhY7TjqXeqWNLaVN…DtEH1csjo11.jpg","PN7QSI3lQeQHOdmwfCrjbixkg.png"]'>
```

now access the value by id

```
var valueArray = JSON.parse( document.getElementById( "news_album" ).value );
```

since it was already an array, JSON.parse was enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1) To use replace and split the string

```
('["1SoW6zxJ58udU6gfT2G2bSZTf.jpg","2DhY7TjqXeqWNLaVN…DtEH1csjo11.jpg","PN7QSI3lQeQHOdmwfCrjbixkg.png"]').replace(/[\]\[]/g,"").split(',')
```

2) To use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse('["1SoW6zxJ58udU6gfT2G2bSZTf.jpg","2DhY7TjqXeqWNLaVN…DtEH1csjo11.jpg","PN7QSI3lQeQHOdmwfCrjbixkg.png"]');
```